# After installion of crystal report it is not visible in toolbox as well as in .net components list

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, .net-4.0

I have created a PoS system in visual studio 2015 using vb.net with .Net Framework 3.5.
Now i have to add reporting options into my application. I tried several time to install and use crystal report.

There are no errors while installing crystal report but after installation and restart the system i cant find crystal report in toolbox not even in .Net Framwork components list.

I am using Windows 8.1 64bit.

I tried different versions of crystal report but in vain. what am i doing wrong?

I consider that maybe there is a specific version of CR for vs 2015.